# Access - Filter on query only records matched in a subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this data on a query, call it Query1, it has a key, named Auth, so Query1.Auth.
Another query, Query2, has different - similar - data, with the Auth key as well, Query2.Auth.

What I wanted to do was, to filter Query1 based on the matched results from Query2. However, there is a nuance, I need to filter only those results which match (actually, I might filter them, based on a condition), whilst leaving the remaining, non-matched, intact.

To be make it a bit more clear, Query1 has a structure similar to:

```
<Auth> <Some Field> <Begin Date> <End Date>
```

Whilst the second query, Query2, is something like

```
<Auth> <Reg Date>
```

So the idea is, to grab the results from Query2 which match those on Query1 (based on Auth, so a LEFT Join), for the matched records, remove those whose Query2.[Reg Date] > Query1.[Begin Date] + 360 And Query2.[Reg Date] < Query1.[Begin Date] (and another condition). And leave the remaining records of Query1 untouched, meaning, those who don't match.

Comment: Sounds straight forward to me. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @ThuroG well, I'm able to filter the first query based on the second. But this filters the records which exist on the second table, and eliminates those who don't. My question is, how can I filter something, if it exists on the second query, else leave it untouched